# Handling Errors From Task in Monix

Tags: task, monix

I have the following code snippet that does a simple HTTP look up for a set of URL's.

```
  def parse(filter: ParserFilter): Task[Seq[HttpBinaryResponse]] = {
    import scalaj.http._
    // Extracts all HTML body anchor elements into an Option
    val browser = new JsoupBrowser {
      override def requestSettings(conn: Connection): Connection =
        conn.timeout(2000)
    }
    val hrefs =
      browser.get(filter.url) >> elementList("a[href]") >?> attr("href")
    val batched = hrefs.distinct.flatten
      .filter(_.startsWith("http"))
      //.map(toTask)
      .map(href =>
        Task {
          HttpBinaryResponse.asHttpBinaryResponse(href, Http(href).asString)
        })
      .sliding(30, 30)
      .toSeq
      .map(chunk => Task.parSequence(chunk))

    Task.sequence(batched).map(_.flatten)
  }
```

I have a Play controller where I call this function and run the Task as below:

```
val batches = appBindings.httpService.parse(parserFilter)
batches.runToFuture.materialize.map {
  case Success(elems) =>
    Ok(Json.prettyPrint(Json.obj(
      "baseURL" -> s"${parserFilter.url}",
      "Total Elements" -> s"${elems.size}",
      "results" -> HttpBinaryResponse.asJson(elems)
    ))).enableCors
  case Failure(err) =>
    Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "error", "message" -> s"${err.getMessage}")).enableCors
}
```

For one of a URL which results in a SSLHandshakeException, I land in the Failure(err) case block, but rather I want to get the following:

1. No matter what the error is, I would like to land in the Success block, where I already capture the error messages for any failed URL.

How do I tweak my Task implementation to do what I need? Any ideas? I tried the onErrorRecoverWith handler, but seems not to have any effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this done as below:

```
def parse(filter: ParserFilter): Task[Seq[HttpBinaryResponse]] = {
    import scalaj.http._
    // Extracts all HTML body anchor elements into an Option
    val browser = new JsoupBrowser {
      override def requestSettings(conn: Connection): Connection =
        conn.timeout(2000)
    }
    val hrefs =
      browser.get(filter.url) >> elementList("a[href]") >?> attr("href")
    val batched = hrefs.distinct.flatten
      .filter(_.startsWith("http"))
      //.map(toTask)
      .map(href =>
        Task {
          HttpBinaryResponse.asHttpBinaryResponse(href, Http(href).asString)
        }.onErrorRecoverWith { case ex: Exception =>
          Task.now(
            HttpBinaryResponse(
              origin = href,
              isSuccess = false,
              errorMessage = Some(s"${ex.getMessage}")))
        })
      .sliding(30, 30)
      .toSeq
      .map(chunk => Task.parSequence(chunk))

    Task.sequence(batched).map(_.flatten)
  }
```